# Form flow returns hyperlinks for email id in Skype Bot

Tags: botframework, skype-bots, formflow

I have an issue while giving the confirmation message in FormFlow for Skype bot.
The issue comes whenever the user gives the "No" for confirmation in the email id column

I get email id as: 
`Group Mailbox Email Address (<a tabindex ="-1" target = "_blank  title="mailto:1152@infy.com" href="mailto:1152@infy.com">1152@infy.com </a>)`

Is there any way i can just change this to:
`Group Mailbox Email Address(1152@infy.com)`

This issue is coming only in Skype bot for web chat it works fine.

Pls let me know if anyone has some workaround for this.

Thanks,
Sheveta

Comment: You say you want to change Group Mailbox Email Address(1152@infy.com) to Group Mailbox Email Address(1152@infy.com). These appear to be the same thing. Is that a typo?

Comment: Ya it was a typo I pasted the same i guess.
Currently its coming as
Group Mailbox Email Address(<a tabindex="-1" target="_blank" title="mailto:1152@infy.com" href="mailto:1152@infy.com">1152@infy.com</a>)    I need it as : Group Mailbox Email Address(1152@infy.com)  without the anchor tags

Comment: Hey,

I was able to resolve by changing the state as below:
.Confirm(async (state) =>
                {                    
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state.GroupMailboxEmailAddress))
                    {
                        state.GroupMailboxEmailAddress = Regex.Replace(state.GroupMailboxEmailAddress, "</?(a|A).*?>", "");
                    }
     }


Thanks,
Sheveta

Comment: Okay, please do edit your question with the correct information and post your answer as the answer

Comment: Hi Kyle while editing the question i see that the question asked is coming in the same format as i have mentioned above. the browser is rendering it without the anchor tags.

Comment: I've edited it for you. You can use backticks: `

Comment: Are you going to post your answer?